# Is this a balanced homebrew race?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, races

Me and my friend made a race with these traits:

1. They do not regain hitpoints through resting.
2. As an action, they can deal necrotic damage to a target within 10 meters and heal as much damage as they dealt. They do not need to roll to hit and can only target one thing at a time. The damage is
   2D6 at level 1
   3D6 at level 6
   4D6 at level 9
   5D6 at level 13
   6D6 at level 17
3. Whenever they cast a spell on a target, they can choose to have it deal necrotic damage equal to their level in addition to normal damage. Doesn't heal them.
4. As an action, they can kill plants to heal. A bush, shrubbery, or 5*5m square of grass and the soil its growing in would heal one hitpoint. A tree could heal 2-20, depending on the size of the tree.
5. +1 intelligence
6. Medium humanoids
7. Speak Common and their own race language
8. The lore of their species is that their anscestors were a group trying to achieve immortality, but something went wrong, leading to them becoming their own species.
9. The species can live for hundreds of years.

Is this balanced in DND 5e?

Comment: This needs a lot more detail before it is really answerable. For instance, #2: is the target a creature or object? do they roll to hit, or is there a save? is the target a single 'thing' or is it an AOE? Take a look at other races that have innate abilities to get an idea of how specific this needs to be.

Comment: I understand. I'll try to be specific

Comment: Followup, does this race heal with spells like cure wounds (or even inverse like inflict wounds a la previous editions?)

Comment: What do you think? Any areas of concern for you, what is your own thought process on some of these features?

Comment: Hi. This is your third question on the site (not counting deleted ones if there are any) and it is on fast track to closure just like the other two. Please, step back, visit Meta, think about how you ask and what clarifications people are regularly asking of you. You may be close to a question ban if you will continue to write the way you do.

Comment: Please see: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question) and [How should I ask about my D&D 5e Homebrew being balanced?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/how-should-i-ask-about-my-dd-5e-homebrew-being-balanced)

Answer (score 5):

### Not Really

- **Ability Score Increases:** Only a +1 to Intelligence, which is way below standard.
- **Age:** No notes about growth, for RP, but mechanically irrelevant.
- **Size:** Medium, no comment.
- **Speed:** Unlisted, which is a problem.
- **Languages:** Common plus one new and unique language. Minimally better than just Common, but kind of weak.

### Features

- **No Healing from Rests:** This is a massive debuff. Huge. It makes Hit Dice essentially useless, negates several class features (i.e. Song of Rest), and makes healing magic, or the Healer feat, a requisite for a group containing this race.
- **Life Leech Power:** This needs either an attack roll or Save DC. Even so, it is a very powerful damaging cantrip, and the self-heal feature makes it better than a first level spell. As a racial ability, this is broken - even as their only form of self-healing it is arguably broken.
- **Blighting Plants:** This provides a self-heal that they can do in or out of combat, as long as there is sufficient plant life. If the environment allows this to function then it is better than healing from rests. However, the DM can take this away at will, so it shouldn't unbalance combat. It will, however, tick off all druids and farmers in the region leading to a world-wide hatred of this species. All of this, plus the inherent ambiguity of the ability, puts a lot of extra work on the Dungeon Master - and DMs are generally already over-worked.
- **Bonus Necrotic Damage:** This is absurdly powerful. Unlimited +[Level] damage to all spells cast. That's just ... too good.

### Conclusion

The drawbacks make it doubtful if they can be played, and negate multiple class features from multiple classes.

The advantages are good enough to build a class around - putting them on a race is absurdly powerful.

**Possible Fixes:**

- The healing powers need usage limitations. The life leech ability should be per Rest (probably usable Proficiency Bonus times per Short Rest). The plant blighting should probably be limited to [Character Level] hit points per Long Rest.
- Bonus Spell Damage needs a limit. Once per Long Rest is still a good racial power. Once per Short Rest is a great racial power. Once per spell cast is too dang good.
- Give a 30' speed.
- Revisit the No Healing ability. Maybe the plant blighting is the new flavor text on Rests. But this is a fundamental change to how the species interacts with the game's recovery mechanics and needs a lot of consideration.

Comment: Possible add to your Blighting plants is that the stated ambiguity of the race puts a LOT of overhead on the DM's shoulders. They then have to determine the size of every plant/tree around the character.

Comment: @aaron9eee Good point. Added.